# Does the .NET code continue executing after IIS time out response?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.NET WebForms app running via IIS.
When a request takes too much time, it returns a Time Out response.
I want to know if the code continues executing on server after the Time Out response or if it is aborted at the exact moment when the Time Out response is sent.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't continue, the thread running your code is aborted. You can catch the exception thrown to abort it if you debug your application, if you wish to test.